# UISearchController displaying not displaying correctly

Tags: uitableview, swift, nspredicate, uisearchcontroller

I have recently used a tutorial of [Add Search to Table View Tutorial in iOS8 with Swift](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift) , which it works great, really simple to understand. The problem I am having is this only allows you to have search for text. As in my textViewCells I also have `detailTextLabel` and an `accessoryView` which is an image. Both of these I want to become part of the search cell once text has been typed. At the moment whatever is in tableViewCell at element 0 is staying there apart from the name. The code used to change update the search controller:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController){

filteredMatchesNames.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
let arrayName = (finalMatchesName as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
filteredMatchesNames = arrayName as! [String]
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

}

and for the `tableView` `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

       var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + cell.frame.width - cell.frame.height - 5, 5, cell.frame.height - 10, cell.frame.height - 10))
       if (self.resultSearchController.active) {

        var dis = ["2222", "4444"]

        var images = UIImage(data: finalMatchesImage[indexPath.row])
        imageView.image = images

        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredMatchesNames[indexPath.row] //This works fine
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dis[indexPath.row] //this doesn't work
        cell.accessoryView = imageView //This doesn't work


        return cell
    }
    else {

        var images = UIImage(data: finalMatchesImage[indexPath.row])
        imageView.image = images

        var dis = ["2222", "444"]

        cell.textLabel?.text = finalMatchesName[indexPath.row] //This works fine
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dis //This works fine
        cell.accessoryView = imageView //This works fine

       return cell
    }

}
```

The full code is inside the link, although I think the problem should just be inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if I can make it so the whole cell is searched and not just the text.

Comment: You could create a `NSDictionary` with a form like (in pseudo code) `{{keyRow1:{text:text1,details:detailsText1}, {keyRow2:{text:text2,details:detailsText2}}`, and use a predicate `(SELF.text CONTAINS[c] %@ OR SELF.details CONTAINS[C] %@, textToSearch, textToSearch)`.

Comment: Thanks, could you put this into more of an answer so I can understand better?